# What is the purpose of Templates in iWork Pages

Tags: macos, templates, iwork-pages

As we launch Pages 09, it prompts us to choose the item from "Text processing" and "Templates".

What is the purpose of "Templates" ?

Actually, i expect from template the definition of document styles and common layout.

Also, i expect to create the normal document from Template.

But, i didn't noticed all of that, while working with iWork Pages 09.

All, what i can do - is just to create the template ... and what next to do with it ?

I don't understand the logical continuation of the workflow, means by Pages, when we have to deal with templates ...

Comment: (*Sorry for editing at same time as you*)

Answer (score 0):

They are built in formatting placeholders.  The point of them is to provide you with a formatting layout for certain documents (reports, letters, envelopes, et cetera, et cetera) so you do not need to set the layout manually for what you want to do, thereby making it a lot easier and faster to use.